# stats - determine limiting distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, limits, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence

Let $Y_{1} < Y_{2} < ... < Y_{n}$ be the order statistics of a random sample from a distribution with pdf $f(x) = e^{-x} , 0 < x < \infty$, zero elsewhere. Determine the limiting distribution of $Z n = ( Y_{n} – ln(n) )$

Course textbook is Introduction to Mathematical Statistics, Seventh Edition, by Robert V. Hogg, Joseph W. McKean, Allen T. Craig., this is from ch. 5.2.

I understand that I need to do something like $F_{Z_{n}} = P(Y_{n} - ln(n)\leq z) = P(Y_{n} \leq z + ln(n))$, but I can't figure out what to do after this step.

Comment: Hint: Since $Y_n$ is the highest value in an i.i.d. sample of size $n$, what is $P(Y_n\leqslant y)$?

Comment: $Max_{x_{i}}$? I'm still confused. I know I need to use $z+ln(n)$ and $f(x)=e^{-x}$, but I'm lost after that.

Comment: Forget $z+\ln n$ for the moment. What is $P(Y_n\leqslant y)$?

Comment: I'm going to guess: $f(x)$ is exponential, so $P(Y_{n} \leq y) = 1-e^{-y}$?

Comment: This would be for only one exponential random variable. But here you have $n$ and $Y_n$ is their maximum--so $Y_n\leqslant y$ when $________$ and $P(Y_n\leqslant y)=$ $________$.

Comment: When x=0, because that's when f(x) is largest? so $P(Y_{n} \leq y) = 0$?

Comment: "$Y_n\leqslant y$ when $x=0$" Sorry, but what are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

First, we obtain the CDF of $X$.
$$
\begin{align}
F_X(x)&=\int_0^xf(t)\ dt\\
\text{Pr}[X\le x]&=\int_0^x e^{-t}\ dt\\
&=-\left.e^{-t}\right|_{t=0}^x\\
&=1-e^{-x}.
\end{align}
$$

Note that from transformation $Z_n = Y_n - \ln\ n$, we have $Y_1<Y_2<\cdots<Y_n\le Z_n$ implies $X_i\le Z_n$, for $i=1, 2,\cdots, n$. Therefore, the fact that $X_i$s are **i.i.d.** implies
$$
\begin{align}
F_{Y_n}(y)&=\text{Pr}[Y_n\le y]\\
&=\text{Pr}[Y_n\le z+\ln\ n]\\
&=\left(\text{Pr}[X_i\le z+\ln\ n]\right)^n\\
&=\left(1-e^{-(z+\ln n)}\right)^n\\
&=\left(1-e^{-z}e^{-\ln n)}\right)^n\\
&=\left(1-e^{-z}\cdot\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\\
&=\left(1-\frac{e^{-z}}{n}\right)^n.\\
\end{align}
$$
Thus, as $n\to\infty$, the limiting distribution of $Z_n = Y_n - \ln\ n$ is
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}F_{Y_n}(y_n)&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{e^{-z}}{n}\right)^n\\
&=\Large\color{blue}{\exp\left(-e^{-z}\right)}.
\end{align}
$$

$$\\$$

---

$$\Large\color{blue}{\text{# }\mathbb{Q.E.D.}\text{ #}}$$